# How can I allow a Python code to open "%temp%" folder for any user?

Tags: python-3.x, user-accounts

I have some users on my PC and I try to create a Python code to open `%temp%` folder, but the problem is that it works under my account only. When I use the same code on a different account it does not work on the same PC.

My folder path >> **C:\Users\MyAccount\AppData\Local\Temp** <<,
the problem error with this user 'MyAccount'

**This is my code:**

```
  import webbrowser
  webbrowser.open('C:\Users\MyAccount\AppData\Local\Temp')
```

I need to pass the correct *userFolder* to my code to work with.

Example:

> ```
> my account the path >> **C:\Users\MyAccount\AppData\Local\Temp**
> on different account >> C:\Users\ **?** \AppData\Local\Temp
> **?** = it should be the name of the user.
> ```

Could you please advise me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pathlib` is an option (comes with Python 3.4+) you can use

```
from pathlib import Path
Path.home() / 'AppData' / 'Local' / 'Temp'
```

if not, try

```
from os import path
path.expanduser('~/AppData/Local/Temp')
```